# How does Activity function works in our MainActivity

Tags: android

How are the functions of an activity or Service such as `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()` or `onBind()` are evoked and executed when we write `startService(intent)` in our MainActivity?

They are not constructors that they will be called automatically.

How do they get called?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, onStartCommand comes under unbounded service and onBind comes under bounded service.
Ok, when a service is called by startService command, firstly it calls the onCreate function then it calls onStartCommand(unbounded services). After that, the service starts running until it's stopped by itself or by other factors. 
Same happens in bounded services, the only difference is that, instead of onStartCommand, it calls onBind Command.

1) Started Service
A service is started when component (like activity) calls startService() method, now it runs in the background indefinitely. It is stopped by stopService() method. The service can stop itself by calling the stopSelf() method.

2) Bound Service
A service is bound when another component (e.g. client) calls bindService() method. The client can unbind the service by calling the unbindService() method.

The service cannot be stopped until all clients unbind the service.

for more info, you can refer lifecycle of services:- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: My question is Who calls these functions? since there is no main().